# Variable stored is not being carried through

Tags: variables, powershell, active-directory

Trying to figure out why a variable I'm declaring is not being used.  I'm wondering if there is some behavior that I'm not aware of and hoping some can enlighten me.  In the beginning of my script, I'm basically creating a function asking user for input of an AD user id and store it as a variable.  I then use that variable to check if it's in AD.  It loops until a valid user id is entered.  It then takes userid variable and checks to see if a folder with the name of the userid variable exists in a specified directory.

The code seems to execute as expected with the exception that userid variable is not being carried through to the bottom of the script.  To validate it, I wrote out what the script saw as the variables.  Below is the script and the output. Any ideas?

```
#Function to obtain userid and check if id exists in Active Directory
Function IDCHECK {
  $error.clear()
  $useid = Read-Host 'Enter the User ID to set the permission'
  Try {Get-ADUser $useid > $null}
  Catch {"UserID does not exist.  Check the UserID and try again."}
  IF (!$error) {
    Write-Host $useid "exists in AD...proceeding" -foregroundcolor Green
  }
}

Do {IDCHECK}
While ($error.count -gt 0)

#Test if folder with name of userid exists
IF (Test-Path C:\Temp\$useid) {
  $homefolder="C:\Temp\$useid"
  Write-Host "Folder exists...proceeding to apply permission" -foregroundcolor Green
  Write-Host "Processing User:" $useid
  Write-Host "Current Directory to act upon:" $homefolder
}
```

Here is the output:

```
~~~~~~~~ Folder Permission Application Script ~~~~~~~
Enter the User ID to set the permission: tdr
tdr exists in AD...proceeding
Folder exists...proceeding to apply permission
Processing User: 
Current Directory to act upon: C:\Temp\
```

Comment: Please tag the language/technology you are using. Also include this in the title. Otherwise, the question appears more theory-based and open-ended.

Comment: did realize that.  thank you for pointing it out.  adjusting now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick testing seems to indicate that calling your function in the `do {}` block runs it in a non-current scope (perhaps it treats it like a script and gives it its own scope?).

This means, therefore, that your assignment to `$useid` in the function is not being done in the global scope and so cannot be seen from outside of the function/`do` block.

Which makes the solution to this problem explicitly assign to the global variable in the function.

```
$global:useid = Read-Host 'Enter the User ID to set the permission'
```

Comment: That would totally explain the behavior.  Didn't know you can make a variable global like that.  Very cool.  Tested on my end and works as expected.  Cheers Etan!

Answer (score 0):

When you assign values to a variable, you also have to consider the scope of the variable.

If you want to save the variable $useid even outside the scope of the function you can prefix the variable name with either script or global.

So the code that saves the userid would be.

```
$global:useid = Read-Host 'Enter the User ID to set the permission'
```

Read the following [article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847849.aspx) regarding variable scope in powershell if you want more information on the topic.

Look at the following sample script to see how local scope is used inside the function and thus the variable is in fact destroyed when leaving the function.

```
function testVariableScope
{
    $var1 = "setup in testVariableScope function"
    return $var1
}
$var1 = $null
echo "`$var1=$var1"
echo "running function" 
testVariableScope > $null
echo "`$var1=$var1"
echo "running again, and assign var1 to return value"
$var1 = testVariableScope
echo "`$var1=$var1"
```

Output:

```
$var1=
running function
$var1=
running again, and assign var1 to return value
$var1=setup in testVariableScope function
```

Comment: As far as I know (and read when I looked this up) functions don't have their own scopes. I assume the `do` block must be an implicit script for functions or something but I can't actually find reference to that. Do you know why the scope is tripping things up here? (Notably `do {$f="foo"}while($false); $f` *does* assign to `$global:f` it seems.)

Answer (score 0):

As others have already pointed out, your issue is caused by variables of the same name in different scopes, and can be mitigated by working with a global variable. However, I would advise *against* actually doing this, for [various reasons](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad). For instance, it's hard to keep track of what value global variables have at any given point in your code, since they can be changed anywhere in your code, which makes your code both harder to understand and harder to test. They also may introduce unwanted/unneeded dependencies between otherwise unrelated parts of your code, which makes it harder to maintain or modularize your code.

A better approach from a coding perspective is to have your function return the validated user ID and exit from the loop when the returned value is not `$null`:

```
function Get-ValidatedId {
  $id = Read-Host 'Enter the User ID to set the permission'
  if (Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$id'") {
    $id
  } else {
    Write-Host "UserID '$id' does not exist. Check the UserID and try again."
  }
}

do {
  $userID = Get-ValidatedId
} until ($userID -ne $null)
```

You could even refactor the loop into the function:

```
function Get-ValidatedId {
  do {
    $id = Read-Host 'Enter the User ID to set the permission'
    if (-not (Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$id'")) {
      Write-Host "UserID '$id' does not exist. Check the UserID and try again."
      $id = $null
    }
  } until ($id -ne $null)
  $id
}

$userID = Get-ValidatedId
```

The above code samples use a filter expression for `Get-ADUser` to avoid errors in case of non-existing account names, and also use an [approved verb](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714428%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) so that the function name is compliant to PowerShell [coding conventions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878270%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for streamlining that.  I do want to adhere to coding best practice/conventions so thank you for the reference.  Changing up now.  Cheers